# Getting NoSuchMethodException when running class despite method being in .class file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a backend for a project at my university and hit an error I do not comprehend.

I am working with IntelliJ, Gradle and use Spock as a testing environment.
One if the goals of the project is to utilize Amazons NoSQL Database solution DynamoDB.
To test the methods of the backend AmazonDB Local is used.

Currently I am writing tests for the various methods of the backend... or at least i tried.
When I run my first test i get a NoSuchMethodException as soon as "GetBookWithTitle" method is reached. (Funny fact: the method "AddBook" seems to be working just fine).

This is the code of the Test:

```
def "Test adding a book to the database"(){
    when: "Adding a book"
        methods.AddBook("TestBook", "Sebastian Müller", 1990, "Gregors", "FunkyTestCover", mapper);

    then: "The book should be added"
        methods.GetBookWithTitle("TestBook", mapper) != null;
}
```

This is the source of the "GetBookWithTitle" method:

```
public Book GetBookWithTitle(String title, DynamoDBMapper mapper){
    Book result = mapper.load(Book.class, title);
    return result;
}
```

What I tried:
 - Cleaning the project with the corresponding gradle task
 - deleting the "build" folder of the project by hand
 - decompiling the .class file to make sure "GetBookWithTitle" IS present

So my question is: Has somebody out there a clue from where this error originates?

If the information provided are not sufficient I will give you more :)

Comment: I have not worked with IntelliJ, but I know that NoSuchMethodException is thrown during a reflective operation (using reflection). This tells me that there might be conflicting class (same name) being loaded before the one that has the `GetBookWithTitle` method, or you are just using the wrong class altogether.

Comment: But then: how does the AddBook Method work which is declared in the same class as GetBookWithTitle? Would he not throw the Exception as soon as he reaches any method declared in the class when there is a class conflict?

Comment: Make sure the method name is spelled correctly and the number of arguments and type is the same. When you use reflection, these sort of issues won't surface until you run the application.  Just use a logical process of elimination: 1) make sure that the class you are using is in the classpath, and that 2) there isn't a conflicting class loaded before, 3) the method is indeed there (spelled the same) and that you are passing valid arguments to it.

Comment: Have you tried using methods.GetBookWithTitle in a separate test?

Comment: The stack trace might help to explain what's going on.

Comment: You might have more success with reflection if you follow normal coding rules for methods. Try renaming your methods with lowercase letters as first letter eg getBookWithTitle instead of GetBookWithTitle.

Comment: Peter is right. The exception alone tells you what is going on. The method in question is being called reflectively and it is not in the class being used. The stack trace should give you enough information to get to the root cause of the problem. Compare the class you THINK is being called, and check the path of the class BEING used. If they are the same, check the method name, argument order and type. One of those things is bound to be wrong.

Comment: I will do what you guys suggest. Thank you for the input. I am right back after trying everything :)

Comment: It could be a Spock bug, but there isn't enough information provided to investigate. It could also be a bug in the code, or in Groovy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i found the answer. It was something completely else and related to DynamoDB and its feature to map database items to java classes.
The mapper class obviously needs a standard constructor which my Book class had not.

For those who are interested:

The DynamoDBMapper.load method calls internally Class.NewInstance(). This method can only use the standard constructor/ constructor without arguments. As there was no such constructor in my class he threw the NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: If you add @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Book") to your class, you actually don't need the ad-hoc constructor.

Comment: You're not right. Default construcotr is necessary, same as getter and setter